# Orthogonal Projection onto Range of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $P_{R\left(A\right)}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $A$, i.e. $R\left(A\right)$, then show that $A^{T}P_{R\left(A\right)}=A^{T}$. So far I have that
$$A^{T}P_{R\left(A\right)}=A^{T}P_{R\left(A\right)}^{T}=\left(P_{R\left(A\right)}A\right)^{T}.$$
I am stuck at the last step. How does $P_{R\left(A\right)}A=A$? My textbook says that if $\operatorname{rank}\left(A\right)=r$ and $B_{m\times r}$ is a matrix whose columns form a basis for $R\left(A\right)$, then $P_{R\left(A\right)}=B\left(B^{T}B\right)^{-1}B^{T}$. Additionally, it says that if $\operatorname{rank}\left(A\right)=n$, then $P_{R\left(A\right)}=A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}$. It's easy to see that if $\operatorname{rank}\left(A\right)=n$, then by substituting, we get $P_{R\left(A\right)}A=A$, but the problem statement does not mention anything about the rank of $A$.

Comment: If $P$ is projection on a subspace $M$ then $Px=x$ for all $x \in M$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for the hint. I understand this, but I'm not sure how this fact applies.

Comment: $P_{R(A)}Ax=Ax$ because $Ax \in R(A)$.

Comment: Both of the answers below are good, but it might be worth saying explicitly that if you're given two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $Ax=Bx$ for every $x$, then in fact $A=B$. This is because, e.g. you can choose $x$ to be the standard basis vectors $e_i$, and then $Mx$ is simply the $i^\text{th}$ column of $M$. So, using each $e_i$ in turn that the first column of $A$ is the same as the first column of $B$, the second column of $A$ is the same as the second column of $B$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ \mathbb R^n=R(A) \oplus R(A)^{\perp}$ and $R(A)^{\perp}=ker(A^T)$.

Let $P=P_{R(A)}$, then we have

$Px=x$ for all $x \in R(A)$ and $Px=0$ for all $x \in ker(A^T)$.

Hence:

$A^TPx=A^Tx$ for all $x \in R(A)$ and $A^TPx=0=A^Tx$ for all $x \in ker(A^T)$.

Answer (score 1):

*["] How does $P_{R(A)}A=A$? [."]*

- $\forall x\in \mathbb R^n, Ax\in R(A)\subseteq\mathbb R^m$.
- The behavior of $P$ [on its range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) is just identity, i.e. $P_{R(A)}=I_{R(A)}.$ This is can be proved by $P^2=P$, since $P$ ***is*** projection.